# Convert legacy code to Spring dependency injection

Tags: java, spring

The legacy code snippet is shown as below. What I want to do is to convert this code to Spring. But the problem is Spring managed the dependency on it's own. My question is how to inject the `serviceId` provided by constructor?

```
public class MyService{
    public Attribute getAttribute(){
        int serviceId =1;
        new ServiceDao(serviceId).getAttribute();
    }
}


class ServiceDao{
    private int serviceId;

    ServiceDao(int serviceId){
        this.serviceId = serviceId; 
    }

    public Attribute getAttribute(){
        //to get attribute
    }
}
```

Comment: use `@Autowired` on constructor and setters

Comment: Is that `serviceId` value really hardcoded in `MyService`? If not, please provide a hint about where it's coming from.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu Hi It's same passing id from factory.. new MyServiceFactory(serviceId) and then call get Attribute

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped you. Please accept it if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are trying to create new objects each time you call

```
new ServiceDao(serviceId).getAttribute();
```

This is purely against dependency injection. As your logic is based on the service ID you can create a service class as follows

```
@Service
class ServiceDao{

    ServiceDao(){

    }

    public Attribute getAttribute(int serviceId){
        //to get attribute
        //return attribute based on service Id,
       //if(serviceId==1)
       //{ return new Attribute("Red");}

    }
}
```

Your Myservice can be something like this

```
  @Service
  public class MyService{

    @Autowired
    ServiceDao dao;

    public Attribute getAttribute(){

        int serviceId =1;
        return dao.getAttribute(1);

    }


}
```

Comment: I think you should also provide an example with constructor injection.